# Issue with Javascript attempting to store result of callback into an object

Tags: javascript

I am doing a RSS feed scrape and taking the values of the data and placing them into a object.

One of the keys of this object I have attempted to attach a method call that takes the another key/value pair from the same object and then pass into and then return the result of the methods call back function.

I am having issues.

Any ideas?

```
for(var z = 0; z < Submit_movies_feedData.items.length; z++){
  sixNineContent = {
    title : Submit_movies_feedData.items[z].title,
    pubDate : Submit_movies_feedData.items[z].pubDate,
    image : Submit_movies_feedData.items[z].image,
    link : Submit_movies_feedData.items[z].link,
    adfly : adfly.short(this.link,function(urlAdfly){
      return urlAdfly;
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Basically I want to be able to take the link value and pass into the adfly value and the result will be stored into the objects key adfly.

Comment: What are the issues that you are having? What is the expected value of `sixNineContent.adfly` and what is the value you are getting with your current script? What does `adfly.short` do?

Comment: I continue to get a undefined...

The adfly.short is a simple npm that works great, it is a shorten url service... But when I try to return the value of the adfly.short and place the value into the sixNineContent.adfly... i get undefined....

Answer (score 0):

`adfly.short` is an asynchronous function, so the callback won't work the way you've written it. You need to wait for the result before you can add it to an object.

Comment: Yes exactly... but how do i wait for the returned objects async function to finish and then store the value when it completes?

Comment: You could assign the variable `sixNineContent` inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

build the object after the async function completes:

```
for(var z = 0; z < Submit_movies_feedData.items.length; z++){
  adfly.short(this.link,function(urlAdfly){
      return urlAdfly;
      sixNineContent = {
        title : Submit_movies_feedData.items[z].title,
        pubDate : Submit_movies_feedData.items[z].pubDate,
        image : Submit_movies_feedData.items[z].image,
        link : Submit_movies_feedData.items[z].link,
        adfly : adfly
      };
  })

}
```

Comment: I tried what you are suggesting but I am getting no data for the adfly object.